# Unable to access the webapp from the docker container

Tags: .net, docker

I can run the webapp in the localhost without docker container
[image]

I have created the docker image and started the container.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I can't access the webapp from the docker container.

[image]

Comment: Could you show us your docker run comnad?

Answer (score 0):

We might need to expose port from docker by `-p` parameter, otherwise, we can't access it outside.

From your information, we can try to expose `5005` port from container, because `webapp3:v1` seems to use that port.

```
docker run ..... -p 5005:5005 .....
```

There is some description from [Container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

> -p 5005:5005：Map TCP port 5005 in the container to port 5005 on the Docker host.